# setState returning: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

So i'm making this React exercise where i use setState but it's returning the following error.

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_reactName, _targetInst, type, nativeEvent, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles, cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped})

Here's the code.

`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";  
export default class Mega extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
        qtdeNum: this.props.qtdeNum
    }

    this.alterarQtdeNum = this.alterarQtdeNum.bind(this)
}
alterarQtdeNum = (qtde) => {
    this.setState({qtdeNum: qtde})
}

render() {
    return (
        
        <><p className="pnum">Gerador de Mega-Sena - {this.state.qtdeNum} </p><input type='text' placeholder="Qtde de Numeros" value={this.state.qtdeNum}
            onChange={this.alterarQtdeNum}></input></>

    )
}
```

}`

I noticed this has to do with the this.setState({qtdeNum: qtde}) line as everytime i alter qtde, exemple: this.setState({qtdeNum: this.qtde}) the error stops showing but the qtdeNum doesn't change the state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `onChange` event handler, which receives an event object, not the value of the input field. You're trying to set state directly with the event object.

Try changing this:

```
    alterarQtdeNum = (qtde) => {
        this.setState({qtdeNum: qtde})
    }
```

to this:

```
    alterarQtdeNum = (event) => {
        this.setState({qtdeNum: event.target.value})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you this code.
I just add one static value instead of your props.

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
  qtdeNum: "10",
 };

   this.alterarQtdeNum = this.alterarQtdeNum.bind(this);
 }
  alterarQtdeNum = (qtde) => {
    this.setState({ qtdeNum: qtde.target.value });
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
    <h3>{this.state.age} years old</h3>
    <p className="pnum">Gerador de Mega-Sena - {this.state.qtdeNum} </p>
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Qtde de Numeros"
      value={this.state.qtdeNum}
      onChange={this.alterarQtdeNum}
    ></input>
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```

If you notice in **alterarQtdeNum** method if you console log your **qtde** you got full element over there you have to get value by qtde.target.value.